# compareTo and equals in PriorityQueues

Tags: java, equals, compareto

i'm a little confused with all the "If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave strangely." warnings in the Javadoc.
I'm not even sure anymore a PriorityQueue is what i need...

My situation is this:
I have a class Event with an integer timestamp and some other fields.
I'm looking for a datastructure, in which I can insert these events and which sorts the events by timestamp.
Different events can have the same timestamp, so - if I understand correctly - compareTo and equals would be inconsistent.

My first approach was to let the Event implement Comparable and provide compareTo like this:
public int compareTo(Event e) {
  return this.timestamp - e.getTimestamp();
}

I don't understand how I'm supposed to solve this. I thought about creating a custom Comparator, but the same warning about strange behaviour pops up in the Comparator's javadoc as well.
I don' want to insert multiple equal instances of an event, i just want them to be sorted by timestamp.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Edit:
I just want the Events to be sorted by timestamp. It could very well be, that two different events have the same timestamp. So compareTo would return 0, because they have the same timestamp and are equal for the purpose of sorting. But equals() would not return true, because they are different events.
I'm not sure, a PriorityQueue is the right thing to use. I looked at SortedSet, but it had the same warnings about the consistency of compareTo and equals.
Maybe I'm tackling this from the wrong angle, I don't know...

Comment: Can you override equals?

Comment: @Yet Another Geek: Yes, I could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Different events can have the same timestamp
>
> and which sorts the events by timestamp

That latter requirement is somewhat unclear. Should the Collection's iterator return instances in sorted order? Or should the collection, if you `poll()` in a loop, return its former contents in sorted order?

**`iterator()` returns elements in order**

That wouldn't be the case for a `PriorityQueue`. You could use a `SortedSet`, but those require the sort order to be consistent with equals, which, as you note correctly, you can't achieve. As far as I know, there is no `Collection` in the JDK that would keep its elements in sorted order for a sort order that considers some elements equal. However, you could use an array or `ArrayList`, and sort it manually after changes using `Arrays.sort` or `Collection.sort`. If the collection changes rarely, this is the approach I'd choose. If it changes frequently, you'll have to look beyond the JDK or implement the data structure yourself.

**`poll()` returns elements in sorted order**

That's what a priority queue is good for. A `PriorityQueue` does not require the `Comparator` (or implementation of `Comparable`) to be consistent with equals; its JavaDoc clearly writes:

> The *head* of this queue is the *least* element with respect to the specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily.

Moreover, the implementation of `PriorityQueue` in JDK 6 uses `equals` only to implement `indexOf(E)`, `contains(Object)` and `remove(Object)`, neither of which use the comparator in any way. So there really isn't a way consistency with equals could matter for this `Collection`.

**Comparable vs. Comparator**

Note that it doesn't matter whether you implement Comparable or Comparator as far as consistency with equals is concerned. For a `SortedSet`, either must be consistent with equals, for a `PriorityQueue`, `Collection.sort` or `Arrays.sort`, neither has to be.

**`TreeSet` and consistency with `equals`**

Lifted from the comments:

> `TreeSet` is a SortedSet and explicitly states to only rely on compareTo/compare. It says explicit: "The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface."

If you quote, please quote all relevant parts. The full paragraph reads:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be *consistent with equals* if it is to correctly implement the `Set` interface.  [...] This is so because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set *is* well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface.

So yes it is well-defined, but it doesn't do what the question calls for: If you pass `TreeSet.add` an `Event` with the same timestamp as another `Event` in the set, the new `Event` will be considered a duplicate and not added, even though the `Event`s are not `equal`. The question asks about sorting a `Collection`; that should not eliminate `Events` that duplicate a sort key, should it?

Comment: `TreeSet` is a SortedSet and explicitly states to only rely on compareTo/compare. It says explicit: "The behavior of a set
 _is_ well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface."

+1 very good answer anyway

Comment: @meriton: I don't iterate over the Collection, so there's no need for the iterator to return the elements in order. At the moment, I am using peek() and remove() to retrieve the least element from the PriorityQueue. So what you're saying is, that in my case, the inconsistency between compareTo and equals is not a problem?

Comment: Exactly. BTW, using `poll()` is marginally more efficient than `peek()` followed by `remove(Object)`.

Comment: @meriton: Splendid. BTW, I'm using peek() and remove(), because I first have to determine if I want to remove the head from the Queue.

Comment: @meriton You're right when it comes to the point if SortedSet is the right data structure or not. But you said: "As far as I know, there is no Collection in the JDK that would keep its elements in sorted order for a sort order inconsistent with equals." But the TreeSet in fact does it. But it treats elements equal by it's comparator. And a set do not contain duplicates. So yes, it is the wrong data structure in this case here. Same here for old implementation of PriorityQueue and its remove method which treated elements equal by comparator - as far as I know.

Comment: @Fatal: You're right, that was inaccurate, I have edited it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

> If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave strangely.

That just means that if and only if `e1.equals(e2)` then `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0`.

And if and only if `!e1.equals(e2)` then `e1.compareTo(e2) != 0`.

That is what you have to do to make both methods consistent.

So by the way you implement compareTo you should also override equals() as:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Event e) {
    return this.timestamp.equals(e.timestamp);
}
```

*Note: I don't know timestamp's data type, but if it is a primitive type, use `==` instead of `equals()` for the overriden method.*

Comment: It should be `if and only if`. So it is also the other way around: If `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` then `e1.equals(e2)`.

Comment: @Fatal Good observation, added it to answer.

Comment: @Marcelo: I understand what it means for compareTo and equals to be consistent. But, as stated in the question, I could have different events with the same timestamp. These events would not be equal in the sense of equals(), but compareTo would return 0.

Comment: @foobar You've to implement a Comparator then in order to not violating the contract. I updated my answer.

Comment: @foobar Can you tell me what determines the equality, or what other properties the Event class has?

Comment: @Marcelo: I'm not concerned that much with the question of equality. I need a datastructure that, while retrieving, returns the Events ordered by their timestamp. Other propeties are some Strings denoting sender, receiver and content of the event.

Comment: @foobar Use the PriorityQueue with your Custom comparator, it will have the behavior that you expect. Ignore the warnings in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement `Comparable` then you should also override `equals(Object)`, because `compareTo` should only return zero if and only if `equals` return true.

> compareTo(T) should only return zero if and only if equals(Object) return true.

And that's not all. Due to another contract you should/must override `hashCode()` when you override `equals`.

> Equal objects must have equal hashcodes.

```
public class Event implements Comparable<Event> {

    private long timestamp;

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return this.timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Event o) {
        return (this.timestamp < o.timestamp ? -1
                : (this.timestamp == o.timestamp ? 0 : 1));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (this.timestamp ^ (this.timestamp >>> 32));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Event) {
            return this.timestamp == ((Event) obj).timestamp;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

`compareTo`, `equals` and `hashCode` implementation was taken from the implementation you can see in `java.lang.Long`. You can also generate these methods by an IDE like Eclipse.

If you want to have a compareTo that evals to 0 when equals must return false (as stated in another comment), then you must implement a Comparator instead of implementing Comparable.

```
public class EventComparator implements Comparator<Event>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public int compare(Event o1, Event o2) {
        return (o1.getTimestamp() < o2.getTimestamp() ? -1
                : (o1.getTimestamp() == o2.getTimestamp() ? 0 : 1));
    }

}
```

Comment: But the JavaDoc on Comparator also states the warning about inconsistent compareTo and equals.   I'm not sure, what they mean by "strange behaviour" and whether it would manifest in my use-case, though. So maybe I can ignore the warning?

Comment: @foobar Depends on implementation you use. While `Set` says you must be consistent with equals `TeeSet` says explicit in class comment that it's implementation only rely on `compareTo`. You can provide your Comparator to the TreeSet constructor.

For `PriorityQueue` it's a bit more to know about. In general you should have consistent `compareTo` and `equals`. But you can also provide a comparator to the constructor. I would not recommend to use PriorityQueue with inconsistent compareTo and equals, since implementation relies on both compareTo and equals even when Comparator was provided.

Comment: "I would not recommend to use PriorityQueue with inconsistent compareTo and equals, since implementation relies on both compareTo and equals even when Comparator was provided." [citation needed]

Comment: You're right, meriton. My knowledge seems to be outdated about that. They changed implementation of remove from Java 5 to 6. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for insisting!